# What Percentage of Type F Groups are not Poincare Duality Groups?

Tags: algebraic-topology, group-cohomology, cw-complexes

What "percentage" (in a meaningful sense of the term) of Type F groups are not Poincare duality groups (over any coefficient ring, in particular, over $\mathbb{F}_2$)? Of course, it's an open question when a Type F Poincare duality group is the fundamental group of an aspherical manifold.

Comment: What is a meaningful sense of the term in this case? There are several randomness models for finitely-presented groups, the most popular are Gromov's density models. Are you aware of these?

Comment: Yes, that's kind-of the idea. I want to do a construction for Type F groups that aren't fundamental group of aspherical manifolds, but I don't know how many more fish that will net for me over and above fundamental groups of aspherical manifolds. I suspect "most" Type F groups are not Poincare duality groups, just as "most" space form groups https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_form are hyperbolic https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_manifold, but I'd just like to poll what known first, if that's all right

Comment: (I guess a Baire category-type answer is most in what I'm interested: do the Type F Poincare duality groups form a meager set and the Type F non-Poincare duality groups form a residual set https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meagre_set ?)

Comment: I suggest you revise your question, to improve clarity. It is still unclear to me (all the sets in question are countable, so every subset is meager).

Comment: I'll have to think about a "better" way of reformulating it and get back to you (plural).

Comment: BTW, if you just want examples of type-F groups which are not PD group, then it's quite easy. Also, in the Gromov density model, for all densities $<1/2$, with asymptotic probability 1, every group is a 2-dimensional group of type F and not a surface group.

Comment: (I was going to post this last night) I think I see it now: (modulo changing coefficients -- and mod a Lemma to the effect that there is always a Type F group with proscribed homology --) this is just a counting problem. I'll modify the question and post an answer later.

(P.S. Do you have a reference for the above Gromov result?)

Comment: I will add references later on.

Comment: I think this is the reference https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s00208-010-0532-4.pdf - thank you so much!

Comment: (And, lastly, I think the reference is the result I was seeking; I won't add my semi-pro attempt to reproduce it)